# How can I convert an array of objects to array with a unique id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, duplicates

I have a array of object like this :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "from": "2022-08-01",
            "to": "2022-08-05",
            "description": "test 1",
            "files": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "hospital_name": "hospital 11",
                    "hospital_id": 11,
                    "period_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "hospital_name": "hospital 11",
                    "hospital_id": 11,
                    "period_id": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "from": "2022-08-06",
            "to": "2022-08-10",
            "description": "test 2",
            "files": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "hospital_name": "hospital 12",
                    "hospital_id": 12,
                    "period_id": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "hospital_name": "hospital 12",
                    "hospital_id": 12,
                    "period_id": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert the array to be like this :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1, // this is period id
            "hospital_name": "hospital 11",
            "hospital_id": 11,
            "from": "2022-08-01",
            "to": "2022-08-05",
            "description": "test 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "hospital_name": "hospital 12",
            "hospital_id": 12,
            "from": "2022-08-06",
            "to": "2022-08-10",
            "description": "test 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I expect the results like that

I try to type my code like this :

```
data.flatMap((period) =>
    period.files.map((file) => ({
        id: period.id,
        hospital_name: file.hospital_name,
        hospital_id: file.hospital_id,
        from: period.from,
        to: period.to,
        description: period.description,
    }))
)
```

But the problem is my code show duplicate id

How can I solve my problem?

Note :

Every period only has one hospital id

Comment: Please don't pad out your question with `#`. The warning is there for a reason

Comment: @evolutionxbox Okay. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need flatMap, just run map on periods and for each period, pick the first file to extract hospital_id and hospital_name like this:

```js
data.map(period => {
  const file = period.files[0];
  return {
    id: period.id,
    hospital_name: file.hospital_name,
    hospital_id: file.hospital_id,
    from: period.from,
    to: period.to,
    description: period.description,
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer looks simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the last result like:

```js
const j = {
  "data": [{
      "id": 1,
      "from": "2022-08-01",
      "to": "2022-08-05",
      "description": "test 1",
      "files": [{
          "id": 1,
          "hospital_name": "hospital 11",
          "hospital_id": 11,
          "period_id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "hospital_name": "hospital 11",
          "hospital_id": 11,
          "period_id": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "from": "2022-08-06",
      "to": "2022-08-10",
      "description": "test 2",
      "files": [{
          "id": 3,
          "hospital_name": "hospital 12",
          "hospital_id": 12,
          "period_id": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "hospital_name": "hospital 12",
          "hospital_id": 12,
          "period_id": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}



console.log(j.data.flatMap((period) =>
      period.files.map((file) => ({
        id: period.id,
        hospital_name: file.hospital_name,
        hospital_id: file.hospital_id,
        from: period.from,
        to: period.to,
        description: period.description,
      }))
    ).filter((value, index, self) =>
      index === self.findIndex((t) => (
        t.id === value.id
      ))))
```

Reference:

- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Did you see the second answer of this question? Answer from yogi. It looks simpler. I try  it and it works

Answer (score 0):

Since the objects in the `files` array are identical (other than the id) you can destructure the properties from the `data` array, and (within that) the first object of each `files` array, and return a new object.

```js
const data={data:[{id:1,from:"2022-08-01",to:"2022-08-05",description:"test 1",files:[{id:1,hospital_name:"hospital 11",hospital_id:11,period_id:1},{id:2,hospital_name:"hospital 11",hospital_id:11,period_id:1}]},{id:2,from:"2022-08-06",to:"2022-08-10",description:"test 2",files:[{id:3,hospital_name:"hospital 12",hospital_id:12,period_id:2},{id:4,hospital_name:"hospital 12",hospital_id:12,period_id:2}]}]};

const out = data.data.map(obj => {

  const {
    from,
    to,
    files: [{ period_id, id, ...rest }],
    description
  } = obj;
  
  return { id: period_id, from, to, description, ...rest }

});

console.log(out);
```

Additional information

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)